# Ember.js: renderTemplates gives DEPRECATED message in router definition

Tags: ember.js, deprecated, ember-router

I just setup a router definition as follows

```
Sp.Router.map(function(match) {
    match('/').to('index');
});

Sp.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplates: function() {
        this.render('index');
    }
});
```

Although it works, I get the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION: Ember.Route.renderTemplates is deprecated. Please use Ember.Route.renderTemplate(controller, model) instead.
```

I don't really undertand what I should do to fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in the question: Please use Ember.Route.renderTemplate(controller, model) (singular form ;))

related commits:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/2468b42f801dc192a6e762293f3590d25274dfd0

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/6d771b7a9389fff826b8f2e500721da6a7ce2fc0

Thanks to @klasspieter: The reasoning behind the change is explained here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1693

Comment: The reasoning behind the change is explained here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1693

Comment: Aha, it is renderTemplate instead of renderTemplates (I missed the 's'), Thnx!!

Answer (score 3):

That's a part of the v2.1 router. There were also other changes. You can have more details here:
[Router v2.1](https://gist.github.com/1b54b0eaf48eabbcff24)

Comment: thnx a lot, I'll check it out!